# Disable enable jsf f:convertDateTime

Tags: jsf, converters

I have two buttons, in one I need `<f:convertDateTime>` to work but in another I need to disable `<f:convertDateTime>` on button click.

I tried the attributes `rendered` and `disabled`, but it didn't work, which was my mistake as it is not available as per the API docs.

Also, is there a way to override the class `javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter` such that whenever `f:convertDateTime` is triggered my class will be called?

Comment: Do you have sample XHTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I tried the attributes rendered and disabled, but it didn't work, which was my mistake as it is not available as per the API docs.*

Indeed, this behavior is not supported. However, as to a possible solution, you basically already gave the answer yourself:

> *Also, is there a way to override the class `javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter` such that whenever `f:convertDateTime` is triggered my class will be called?*

That is possible and will also solve your initial problem. Just register it as `<converter>` in `faces-config.xml` on exactly the [same `<converter-id>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERTER_ID) as `<f:convertDateTime>`.

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>javax.faces.DateTime</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.example.YourDateTimeConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

Therein you could do additional conditional checking, such as checking if a certain button is pressed, or if a certain request parameter is present or absent. If you'd like to continue the default `<f:convertDateTime>` job, just delegate to `super` provided that your converter `extends` from [`DateTimeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html).

E.g. in `getAsObject()`:

```
public class YourDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    @Override
    public void getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        // ...

        if (yourCondition) {
            // Do your preferred way of conversion here.
            // ...
            return yourConvertedDateTime;
        } else {
            // Do nothing. Just let default f:convertDateTime do its job.
            return super.getAsObject(context, component, submittedValue);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have some text displayed based on a button click (correct me if I'm wrong). So it should be something like that:

```
<h:commandButton value="Convert" action="#{bean.doBtnConvert}" />

<h:commandButton value="Don't convert" action="#{bean.doBtnDontConvert}" />

<h:panelGroup id="pgText">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.someDateTime}" rendered="#{bean.convert}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>

    <h:outputText value="#{bean.someDateTime}" rendered="#{not bean.convert}"> />
</h:panelGroup>
```

And in bean you have the following field and methods:

```
private Date someDate;
private boolean convert;

public String doBtnConvert(){
    setConvert(true);
    String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
    return viewId + "?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String doBtnDontConvert(){
    setConvert(false);
    String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
    return viewId + "?faces-redirect=true";
}

// getter and setter for 'someDate' and 'convert' fields
```